# Is there a way to pull data from other tabs in google sheets and keep it separated?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I work at my small family business and am trying to connect as much data as possible. We have a consignment business with roughly 60 accounts. We have it set up so there is a list of all the products we send out, but all of our accounts have different combinations of products and stock levels. I created individual Google sheets that we call "pull sheets" that show which products each store has, how many, and where each product goes in their display. I am trying to create a "master list" that shows which product each store has and the amount of each product they carry, but I want it to show each store individually. I have used importrange to put them all into a single workbook on separate tabs, but I cannot find a solution to bring the information I need to pull from each to one tab in the workbook.
[image] [image]

The photo is a sample of the individual sheets. Each sheet has the same layout but different products and amounts. I am trying to create a master list that Col1 is labeled "products" and all the products that we sell will be listed. The rest of the columns would be "store 1", "store 2", "store 3", etc. Each product would have a number by it if that store sells it or a zero/be blank if they do not carry it.
[image]

Comment: Please DO NOT post images of data - copy or type the text into the question. from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a sample spreadsheet with some data so that we can get a better idea of what you're needing?

Just thinking out loud here, but if you want each tab into one sheet, you could do something like this...

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:G;Sheet2!A1:G;Sheet3!A1:G;Sheet4!A1:G},"select *",1)
```

You would add more sheets according to how many you have. If you notice, each sheet starts in A1. I'm assuming that all the headers have the same name. That's super important when you're combining data from different tabs into one.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.